# Why is the control's in panel gets overwrite everytime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Everytime the button's click event get fired, the label (or any other control) in panel gets overwrite by the new one! Here is the button event.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.ID = "name";
    lbl.Text = Profession.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Panel1.Controls.Add( lbl);
}
```

It everytime remove the previous *label* and add new *label* with the selected item in **DropDownList**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337701/i-want-to-add-dynamic-controls-to-panel-by-button-click-which-should-not-overrid

Comment: @aravind : I'm not developing in vb.

Comment: U can use a code converter online which will convert vb to c#..logic might be the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label is getting initialized on every click that is the problem

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();//here on every click new label initialized
    lbl.ID = "name";
    lbl.Text = Profession.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Replace above code by

```
Label lbl = new Label();
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    lbl.ID = "name";
    lbl.Text = Profession.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if(!Panel1.Controls.Contains(lbl)) //Check here if label already added
         Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Comment: Why are you not adding the label into panel on page startup? Just change text of label on click.

Comment: I am adding multiple labels onclick. Don't want to add until user press button.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the scope of your Label. You are creating a new instance of Label on every click. Take this on class level

```
Label lbl = new Label();
```